# IntelliJ and SBT plugin: not running in current module

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 15 and the IDEA SBT plugin: https://github.com/orfjackal/idea-sbt-plugin

The SBT project has several sub-projects (modules in IntelliJ) and these work fine in my usual SBT terminal workflow.  The `root` sub-project has no Main class.

My SBT Task seems to only run in the `root` sub-project.  I have the intended 'module' highlighted in both the 'Project' pane, and the 'SBT projects' pane of the SBT plugin.

"Run in current module" is checked.

[image: edit configurations]

[image]

Using the SBT Console pane and typing in `project [intended sub-project]` and `run` works.  But I need to get the `run` and `debug` buttons working.  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in

```
[sub-project]/run
```

in the tasks inputbox 
This will execute the run task for that subproject